# Error in run mpi

Tags: c++, mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi

I have a cluster with 4 node ( 12 core for each node)
I run qpms9 ( MPI) on 1 node ( with 12 core) but i can't run the program on 4 node

```
00:48-XXX@node3:~/qpms9-2 > mpiCC main.cpp utils.cpp MyString.cpp -o main
utils.cpp: In function ‘void printLmer(const char*, int)’:
utils.cpp:168:17: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
00:48-XXX~/qpms9-2 > mpirun -np 4 --host node1,node2,node3,node4 main 13-4 -l 13 -d 4
Reading file 13-4
n=20 q=100% L=13 d=4 totalStringLength=12000 alphabet=ACGT of size=4
s=3 n'=6
[node1][0,1,0][btl_tcp_
endpoint.c:572:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() failed with errno=110
[node2][0,1,1][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:572:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() failed with errno=110
```

Comment: `errno=110` is usually "Connection timed out" in case anyone is remotely interested in deciphering this.

Comment: why connection timed out? what can i do?

Comment: Post the network configuration of the nodes. This usually occurs when there are virtual interfaces that are from the same subnet but no physical connectivity exists between them.